# Pyqt4: how to add Margins in Qscintilla properly

Tags: python, pyqt4, margin, qscintilla

I want to make my margin look like this:-
[image: margin design pyqt4]

and i have made like this till now:-
[image: Margin design by user]

with the following code:-

```
self.setMarginType(1,Qsci.QsciScintilla.NumberMargin)
self.setMarginWidth(1,40)
self.setMarginsForegroundColor(QtGui.QColor(120, 128, 120))
self.setMarginLineNumbers(1,True)
```

Please tell is there any mistake in this code, and what code should be added to display markers or margin containing markers(like blue dots at right side of numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

you should define the marker style before you use it.
here is the code :

```
class SimplePythonEditor(QsciScintilla):
    CIRCLE_MARKER_NUM = 0
    ......
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(SimplePythonEditor, self).__init__(parent)
       self.markerDefine(QsciScintilla.Circle,self.CIRCLE_MARKER_NUM)
       self.setMarkerBackgroundColor(QColor(66, 66, 255),self.CIRCLE_MARKER_NUM)
       ......

    def on_margin_clicked(self, nmargin, nline, modifiers):
        # Toggle marker for the line the margin was clicked on
        if self.markersAtLine(nline) != 0:
            self.markerDelete(nline, self.CIRCLE_MARKER_NUM)
        else:
            self.markerAdd(nline, self.CIRCLE_MARKER_NUM)
```

for more details, you can modify eli's demo.
[eli's qscintilla demo](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/01/sample-using-qscintilla-with-pyqt/)

Comment: can u tell me why marker number is used and how from 1 to 31 marker numbers are different from each other

Comment: And How to add a custom marker symbol like with gradient,Pix map or an image etc.